# Help with a framed environment

Tags: framed

Upon trying to create a framed environment using the `framed` package, I stumbled upon a problem I have not been able to resolve. What I am trying to achieve is the following:

[image]

Unfortunately with the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{defn}[1]{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep%
{\color{#1}\hfil\hbox to \hsize{\leaders\hrule height 2pt depth 2pt\hfil}\hfil}\colorbox{yellow!20}%
}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize -\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
\begin{document}
\begin{defn}{blue}
test test
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

I get [image]

The problem is clear, the frame color is correct but the horizontal rule is not being placed correctly. I know that there should be some form of a `\vskip` or the sort but I cannot get how to put. If this has been asked, please redirect me. I prefer using the `framed` package (but and `mdframed` one is welcome.)

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer `framed` over `mdframed`?

Comment: No not really but I like the framed package. Just for the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty straight forward with [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed). You can use (for example)

```
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
            leftline=false,
            rightline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=3pt,
            linecolor=blue]{myframe}
```

[image: screenshot]

If you'd like to have an environment that takes an optional first argument to specify the background colour, then you can use, for example,

```
\newenvironment{defn}[1][yellow!20]{%
\myframe[backgroundcolor=#1]}
{\endmyframe}
```

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xcolor]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
            leftline=false,
            rightline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=3pt,
            linecolor=blue]{myframe}

\newenvironment{defn}[1][yellow!20]{%
\myframe[backgroundcolor=#1]}
{\endmyframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{defn}[red]
\lipsum[2]
\end{defn}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{myframe}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{myframe}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Definitely looking forward for the framed version. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @azetina I posted this because you said an `mdframed` version is welcome...

Comment: @cmhughes you beat me by five seconds :)

Comment: Yes yes. I appreciate it. I just commented that it would be nice now to see a framed version probably from someone else. Your answer is more than welcomed.

Comment: @cgnieder that's happened to me *many* times :)

Comment: What are the differences between `\newenvironment` and `\newmdenv`, which are relevant to the ("average") user of `mdframed`? Only that the former takes an optional argument and the latter doesn't (never does)?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty `\newmdenv` is specially designed to handle all of the keys; `\newenvironment` is more general

Comment: what are "keys"? Which keys? Is it correct that `\newmdenv` doesn't take optional arguments?